# How to parse update CSV file value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I need to preload data into my `tableView` when the app launches. I'm using core data by parsing a .csv file.
I need to update the .csv file time to time. The user must show the update value . 
if I used the following code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let isPreloaded = defaults.bool(forKey: "isPreloaded")
    if !isPreloaded{
        preloadData()
        defaults.set(true, forKey: "isPreloaded")
    }

    return true
}
```

it is only showing the old data of `csv` file. But if i use the following code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    preloadData()
    return true
}

func preloadData() {
    // Load the data file. For any reasons it can't be loaded, we just return


    guard let contentsOfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "menudata",withExtension: "csv") else {
           return
    }

    // Remove all the menu items before preloading
    removeData()
    // Parse the CSV file and import the data
    if let items = parseCSV(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL, encoding:
        String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        for item in items {
            let menuItem = MenuItem(context: context)
            menuItem.name = item.name
            menuItem.detail = item.detail
            menuItem.price = Double(item.price) ?? 0.0
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its showing update value but always loading from `csv` file and not from the database. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code, but I assume that preloadData() is copying the .csv file from the bundle to the User's Documents folder? (otherwise you wouldn't be able to write to it) When you see old data are you looking at the original .csv file in the bundle (which is read-only) ?

Since you are now unconditionally calling preloadData(), preloadData() needs to distinguish where the data is coming from.  If it's not in the database yet, it needs to put it there (you successfully do that), and if you've already done that, it needs to load the data from the database. If you do that correctly, then the rest of your program needs to get its data only from the database.

EDIT:

In preloadData() you are:

reading the .csv from your bundle (every time you start the app)

saving the contents of the csv to your CoreData datastore (every time)

but you never ask the database for data (and probably shouldn't here, anyway).  In your view controller you can query the database for your objects (maybe using a fetch controller)....

Comment: I have added `preloadData()` method.